# SELECT statement with order by returns wrong order

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I want to get result order by name column of `L5_ORDERBY` table, but it gives me wrong order

```
CREATE TABLE L5_ORDERBY 
(
     LVL NUMBER, 
     NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (-20, 'j');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (-30, 'H');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (12, 'G');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (30, 'f');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (1, 'e');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (1, 'e');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (6, 'E');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (1, 'E');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (4, 'c');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (3, 'c');
INSERT INTO L5_ORDERBY VALUES (5, 'b');

SELECT * 
FROM L5_ORDERBY 
ORDER BY NAME DESC;
```

This is the result I get:

| LVL | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| -20 | j |
| 30 | H |
| 12 | G |
| 30 | f |
| 1 | e |
| 1 | e |
| 6 | E |
| 1 | E |
| 4 | c |
| 3 | C |
| 5 | b |

This result Oracle returns has a wrong order by name

Comment: What order do you expect? Please add the desired result

Comment: You have specified that you want the results sorted by the NAME column, in DESCending order .... that is what you have got - j, h, g, f, e, c, b.  If you are perhaps expecting your upper-case letters to be prioritised over your lower-case letters, that will most like come down to the collation setting on your database/server.  Please provide an example of you would like the results to appear, for others to better understand why you think it is not working correctly

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686809/1181250

Comment: If you want case insensitive then use `NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI`, if you want case sensitive then use  `NLS_SORT = BINARY` (or replace `BINARY` with `LINGUISTIC`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Right; if only you specified what "wrong order" means. I *presume* you'd want to do **case sensitive** sort. If that's so, then:

Your current output:

```
SQL> select * from l5_orderby order by name desc;

       LVL NAME
---------- ----------
       -20 j
       -30 H
        12 G
        30 f
         1 e
         1 e
         6 E
         1 E
         4 c
         3 c
         5 b

11 rows selected.
```

Change `nls_sort`

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort = binary;

Session altered.
```

New result:

```
SQL> select * from l5_orderby order by name desc;

       LVL NAME
---------- ----------
       -20 j
        30 f
         1 e
         1 e
         3 c
         4 c
         5 b
       -30 H
        12 G
         6 E
         1 E

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you want to revert the change, then

```
alter session set nls_sort = binary_ci;
```

---

More about it in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG290).

---

If you're on 12c and above, use `collate`:

```
SQL> select * from l5_orderby order by name collate binary desc;

       LVL NAME
---------- ----------
       -20 j
        30 f
         1 e
         1 e
         3 c
         4 c
         5 b
       -30 H
        12 G
         6 E
         1 E

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```